# How to include video (video file, not online video!) in microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word, video, microsoft-office, video-conversion

How can I include video (I mean video file that is on my hdd that will be included inside word file, not online video!) in Microsoft Word 2013/2016? I need to include it as a video that can be played inside Word, I don't need it as usual file attachment.

Comment: Could you improve your question to include such information as to whether you have Internet access or if you have any other restrictions, as one of the answers describes a great solution (embed YouTube) but your question could prove difficult to answer as you are likely to receive a number of different answers that are all valid, but which is the best for your situation?

Comment: please don't do this Word is meant to be used for Writing Documents/Letters that can be printed - how the hell would you print the information which is inside the Movie? - If you wanna do a Presentation there are better Tools like Powerpoint or Prezzi.com eg. - Also if it is a larger Movie think about what happens to your Word Document since the Movie is fully embeded your Word Document will be increased about the same size the Movie has so it will be a pain in the ass for other to open your Word Document if they have an older PC or havn't as much RAM as you have.

Answer (score 4):

I know your concern, just try this:

Let's say that you knew how to embed video source form online.
If you want to embed video from your PC, first you need to enable Developer option.

- Go to file and click Options
- Click Customize Ribbon
- Check Developer
- Then simply click OK

Now got to Developer tab, click Legacy Tools drop box, then More Controls

- Scroll down and hit Windows Media player
- Now, right click on it and select Properties
- In the URL paste the browse URL from your PC
- Disable the Design mode to embed the video from PC and play it in Word 2016.

Comment: This method links preview video to word file but not actually adds video to word file. The video file is not stored in the word file and it needs to remain in the same location to be able to play it. Is there any way to actually include a video file in the word file, so that if I give someone that word file without external video file that person will be able to play it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever tried to convert your video to gif format then copy and paste the converted video file into your document?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked perfectly for my use case, embedding short videos into a Word doc for game development notes. I recorded a short video in .mp4 format then converted it to .gif and this allowed me embed the .gif file in the Word document. It plays on a loop and can be paused, and I can move the original file anywhere I like in my file system. Good answer +1

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to upload your file to YouTube, then insert it as an online video. After uploading the video, use this official quick guide: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Insert-online-video-bf11b812-0243-4f53-a1f9-432fbf7ace2c

Insert online videos that you can watch right in Word without having to leave the document.

Click Insert > Online Video.

In the Insert Video window, you can search for videos on Bing or insert a video’s embed code. You also have the option to add other providers such as YouTube.

When you find the video you want, just click Insert.

If the Online Video button appears grayed out, make sure you’re not in Compatibility Mode. You know you’re in Compatibility Mode if [Compatibility Mode] appears after the document name in the title bar at the top of the Word window. To convert the document, click File > Info > Convert. To learn more about Compatibility Mode, see Use Word 2013 to open documents created in earlier versions of Word.

If you want to add videos from YouTube and you don’t see it as an option, click the YouTube button at the bottom of the Insert Video window. If you don’t see a YouTube icon, make sure you’re Signed in to Office 2013.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Thank you for you your answer but I need to include video file that is on my hdd that will be included inside word file, not online video.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide 2 parts to this answer. the first answers the question on  how to do it. The second is why this is usually not done

1. In word, go to insert tab then select insert hyperlink,
   in the hyperlink window: browse to your hdd and select the video. 
   Done. You can click on this and your video will work.
2. This ties the word document video working to your specific PC. If you want to use the document on different machines, email it to others, etc. then using youtube is better provided there is sustainable good internet access.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need video to be played inside word document. Not just link to video.

Comment: @vasili111 you can't embed the video inside the msword format. At best you can distribute a folder containing both.

Comment: @jiggunjer I decided to install LibreOffice and use Writer. Writer allows including videos in odt format. It is not what exactly I wanted but it can work for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. right click on video file, select Copy
2. in MS Word document wherever you want to insert the video, right click, select Paste.

Comment: The OP specifically asks: "I don't need it as usual file attachment". Your solution is exactly what the OP asked not to give.

Comment: ths does not work. simply puts an icon with the filename  (word 2019)